# Javascript Form Onchange hack with Google Chrome and IE7

Tags: javascript, onchange

```
<form onchange="return valid('form changed')">
 <select>
  <option>uno</option>
  <option>dos</option>
 </select>
 <input type="radio" name="videoDevice" value="cuatro" checked="checked" />
</form>
```

onchange event is not working with google chrome and ie7 ... how to hack it ...
onchange is not required on select tag and we can't use jquery ...

Answer (score 0):

there is no onchange event

you need onsubmit to validate prior to posting to the server
or
to hook up some events on the dom elements onclick, onchange depending on the element
that inform the user directly

Comment: onchange exist and working fine with firefox etc ... only not working with IE7 and chrome

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery on the input as well.

```
$("input").change(function(){ //Do stuff here });
```

Comment: If jquery is not possible I will use basic javascript and attach it to onchange event for each input.